# Sitecore 9.3 Azure Search multi-site search with separate indexes

Tags: indexing, azure-search, multisite

Using Sitecore 9.3 and Azure search.  We have a single Sitecore CM instance setup with two content trees:

- /sitecore/content/siteOne
- /sitecore/content/siteTwo

We have separate CD sites for each of the above sites.  When a user searches in siteOne, we only want results from siteOne's content tree, and likewise for siteTwo.

Is this even possible?  I've searched StackExchange and the Sitecore Community for examples - any examples of how to set this up, and I am not finding anything.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an Azure Search problem. You can use the `ContentSearchAPI` to filter your results based on the path of the items returned.

```
using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_master_index").CreateSearchContext())  
{
  // Create an initial predicate - use .True<T> since we'll be AND'ing this clause together with the search query
  var filterPredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<SearchResultItem>();
    
  // Filter by site
  filterPredicate = filterPredicate.And(x => x.Path.Contains("/sitecore/content/yoursite/home/path"));
  
  // Add your search query to the predicate
  fitlerPredicate = filterPredicate.Where(x => ......);
  
  // Fetch results from the search index using the predicate
  var results = context.GetQueryable<SearchItemResult().Filter(filterPredicate); 
}
```

This will limit the search results to a single sites content. Of course you can get more finely grained if you need to only search within a specific section of content.

Comment: Other option can be, creation of the Site specific custom SOLR index https://sitecorediaries.org/2020/05/24/how-to-create-a-custom-solr-index/

Comment: @AmitKumar Current implementation is using Azure search - we may switch to using Solr, but not for now.